# OpenJDK cross compilation: failed unable to make target

Tags: java, openjdk-11

I need to cross-compile this fork of openJDK https://gitlab.com/gosjava/11/openjdk/-/tree/master/ on host system Kali Linux 2021.3 for target "aarch64-linux-gnu"
As described here https://gitlab.com/gosjava/11/openjdk/-/blob/master/doc/building.md#cross-compiling-the-easy-way-with-openjdk-devkits
And it fails with error:

```
┌──(katya㉿kali)-[~/work/prostor/openjdk]
└─$ cd make/devkit
                                                                                                                                                                                                   
┌──(katya㉿kali)-[~/…/prostor/openjdk/make/devkit]
└─$ make TARGETS="aarch64-linux-gnu"
Building on platform unknown-linux-gnu
host_platforms unknown-linux-gnu
target_platforms aarch64-linux-gnu
find: ‘/home/katya/work/prostor/openjdk/build/devkit/result/unknown-linux-gnu-to-aarch64-linux-gnu’: No such file or directory
Building compilers for unknown-linux-gnu
Targets: aarch64-linux-gnu
for p in  aarch64-linux-gnu; do \
  make -f Tools.gmk download-rpms HOST=unknown-linux-gnu BUILD=unknown-linux-gnu RESULT=/home/katya/work/prostor/openjdk/build/devkit/result OUTPUT_ROOT=/home/katya/work/prostor/openjdk/build/devkit \
              TARGET=$p PREFIX=/home/katya/work/prostor/openjdk/build/devkit/result/unknown-linux-gnu-to-$p && \
  make -f Tools.gmk all HOST=unknown-linux-gnu BUILD=unknown-linux-gnu RESULT=/home/katya/work/prostor/openjdk/build/devkit/result OUTPUT_ROOT=/home/katya/work/prostor/openjdk/build/devkit \
              TARGET=$p PREFIX=/home/katya/work/prostor/openjdk/build/devkit/result/unknown-linux-gnu-to-$p && \
  make -f Tools.gmk ccache HOST=unknown-linux-gnu BUILD=unknown-linux-gnu RESULT=/home/katya/work/prostor/openjdk/build/devkit/result OUTPUT_ROOT=/home/katya/work/prostor/openjdk/build/devkit \
              TARGET=unknown-linux-gnu PREFIX=/home/katya/work/prostor/openjdk/build/devkit/result/unknown-linux-gnu-to-$p BUILDDIR=/home/katya/work/prostor/openjdk/build/devkit/unknown-linux-gnu/$p || exit 1 ; \
done
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/katya/work/prostor/openjdk/make/devkit'
TARGET=aarch64-linux-gnu
HOST=unknown-linux-gnu
BUILD=unknown-linux-gnu
ARCH=aarch64
Tools.gmk:75: *** Unknown base OS .  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/katya/work/prostor/openjdk/make/devkit'
make: *** [Makefile:90: unknown-linux-gnu] Error 1
```

Why? The command `make TARGETS="aarch64-linux-gnu" BASE_OS=OLE6` also fails

```
Tools.gmk:75: *** Unknown base OS OLE6.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/katya/work/prostor/openjdk/make/devkit'
make: *** [Makefile:90: unknown-linux-gnu] Error 1
```

What is wrong? I follow documentation, but ...